# Delete Columns from datatable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I need to delete a lot of columns from my data table.
Does exist any query in C# with LINQ or any command that do this in a simple way by specifying the name of the column?  Something like: dt.DeleteColumn("column name"); Or maybe clone only the column that i need in another dt?

Comment: Why don't you just execute an SQL query with your criteria, example: https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/tables/alter_table.php#:~:text=The%20syntax%20to%20drop%20a,of%20the%20table%20to%20modify.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumncollection.remove?view=netcore-3.1#System_Data_DataColumnCollection_Remove_System_String_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dt.Columns.Remove("IHateThisColumn");
```